# Spring boot - find username from session cookie value

Tags: java, spring-boot, session-cookies

I am currently working on a spring boot application, and I've got a handler which takes the HttpServletRequest as an argument.
I was wondering, is it possible to invoke a bean that - provided the session cookie - can return the information of who made the request? (e.g. username)

Comment: Do you use Spring Security and the user must login?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes, but I solved, I'm posting the solution down

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found this way to make the code work in the desired way.

```
package org.my.package;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.InvalidCsrfTokenException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

import static org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY;


@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class CsrfDeniedHandlerConfig {

    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class CsrfDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

        private final AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

        @Override
        public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
            if (accessDeniedException.getClass().equals(InvalidCsrfTokenException.class)) {
                SecurityContextImpl securityContext = (SecurityContextImpl) request.getSession().getAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY);
                User user = (User) securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
                log.error("Invalid CSRF token request from {}: {}", user.getUsername().toUpperCase(), accessDeniedException.getMessage());
            }
            accessDeniedHandler.handle(request, response, accessDeniedException);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler csrfDeniedHandler() {
        return new CsrfDeniedHandler(new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl());
    }

}
```